# No double quote in hyperlink

Tags: vb.net

I add the hyperlink in code behind in vb.net. I wanted to generate the link like this http://localhost:8010/CardExplorer.aspx?nc=2013+BC+100” target="_blank" >2013 BC 100
However, I used the following code didn't show the double quote. Please someone show me the correct code. thanks in advance.

```
Dim searchlink As New HyperLink
searchlink.Text = cn
searchlink.Attributes.Add("href", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Search") & Server.UrlEncode(cn) & """" & " target=" & """" & "_blank")
                        e.Item.Cells(6).Controls.Add(searchlink)
```

Also I used Chr(34) instead of using """" and the result is same as below.

```
<a href="http://localhost:8010/CardExplorer.aspx?nc=2013+BC+2566&quot; target=&quot;_blank">2013 BC 2566</a></td>
```

Comment: It should automatically escape quotes for your when you use the `add()` method. You need to use an `add()` for each attribute too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the one Attributes.Add() call to add all your attributes.  Because of this it's assuming you want everything in the `href` attribute and is encoding quotes and similar characters appropriately to avoid generating invalid HTML.  Try changing your code to look like this:

```
Dim searchlink As New HyperLink
searchlink.Text = cn
searchlink.Attributes.Add("href", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Search") & Server.UrlEncode(cn))
searchlink.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank")
e.Item.Cells(6).Controls.Add(searchlink)
```

Comment: You're welcome, though I honestly think you should be using Gonzix's solution.  His is far more elegant and uses existing properties of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the hyperlink properties?

```
Dim searchlink As New HyperLink
searchlink.NavigateUrl = "http://foo.com"
searchlink.Target = "_blank"
```

Or even better, add the control on design time

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" ImageUrl="images/pict.jpg" NavigateUrl="http://www.microsoft.com" Text="Microsoft Official Site" Target="_blank" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: I actually like your response better than mine.  Trying to create a coherent answer while typing one-thumbed, standing on a rocking train using an iPhone makes life a trifle difficult, so I didn't have time to look up the Hyperlink object and make the connection to the existing properties.

Comment: I know the feeling... I'm on vacation and using mobile devices is... Well... No as confortable as it could be ;)